# Inline style to PHP

Tags: php

I have a piece of PHP code to grab my post title which I am putting inside of a PHP element on my page builder.

```
$h4 = get_the_title();`echo '<h4>' . $h4 . '</h4>';`
```

I want it to be a H1 but want to style the H1 differently to my global H1 settings.
I would like this H1 centered with font color white and font size 60px.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: This can be done with CSS and HTML classes, neither of which are WordPress specific

Answer (score 2):

Why not add a CSS class to the H1?

`echo '<h1 class="custom-style">' . get_the_title() . '</h1>';`

then in your child theme or custom CSS, apply the style to that class:

```
h1.custom-style { 
    text-align:center; 
    color:#fff;
    font-size:60px; 
}
```

Comment: oops you're very faster than me :)

Answer (score 1):

Replacing your code little bit.

```
$title = get_the_title();
echo '<h1 class="centered-title">' . $title . '</h1>';
```

I changed the heading tag to H1 tag and added a CSS classname **centered-title**. Open your style.css file of your theme or go to Customizer -> Additional CSS box and add this CSS:

```
.centered-title {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 60px;
   text-align: center;
}
```